# When does fasting Erev Rosh Hashanah officially begin and end?

Tags: fast-days, rosh-hashanah-new-year

May seem like a simple question considering erev means evening...

But does fasting erev Rosh Hashanah which is similar to Erev Yom Kippur katan (aka Erev Rosh Chodesh) officially begin at nightfall and extends till minchah ketana?

Answer (score 3):

The Ramma in Orach Chayim siman 581 says it start at amud hashachar and we are not mashlim. The Aruch Hashulchan there and the Mishna Berurah in siman 562 s.k. 10 says that means you don't need to wait till nightfall. But he then brings a Machatzis Hashekel from our siman that says due to the weakening of the generations many people only fast untill mincha gedolah, praying mincha before breaking the fast. 
The piskei tshuvos brings opinions that are even more meikel like a Yaavetz that says you don't have to actually pray mincha first but can eat right away after chatzos.

Comment: is it safe to say its similiar to a day fast or minor fast but actually much shorter?

Comment: Its more meikil in the sense that we are not mikabel it on the day before, it was and for some people still is a minhag.  But in general I would guess you can describe it like you did.

Comment: If Rosh Hashanna is on Shabbat, is the taanit moved to Thursday?